# Congrats to us!

Tags: discussion

Effective yesterday, 16 Dec 2021, Woodworking is officially out of beta!

Congrats to us and thanks to whoever it was that made the original suggestion and to those who participated early enough in the private beta to make this a public beta site.

*Now, if we could only get people to use chat...*

Comment: Guilty as charged. Using comments instead of chat is one of my sins.

Answer (score 2):

I've been on all day and didn't notice.  They told us it was coming but I thought that both I would be told BEFORE it happened and that it probably wasn't going to happen until January...

Still very cool, it's finally here.  I also thought they were going to have actual official elections before, apparently, that will be happening after!

Answer (score 2):

Very Nice.

Wait...no Cheers? Fireworks? Pay Raises?

Well, back to the shop :)

Comment: You get 12 more cookies a year. I'll tell HR.

Comment: Man, _more_ cookies? Do they all come with the giant GDPR warning banners covering half the browser?